# Отправка документа на печать

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, print

На сервере генерирую документ excel и отправляю его на клиентское приложение. Для генерации использую библиотеку [**ASPOSE**](https://www.aspose.com/). По итогу на клиенте имею массив `byte[]`, который могу преобразовать в `Workbook` и `Worksheet`. И вот тут главный вопрос, каким образом можно открыть стандартное диалоговое окно выбора принтера и отправить на печать документ находящийся в одном из перечисленных мною состояний (`byte[]`, `Workbook`, `Worksheet`) ?

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(workbookBytes);
var workbook = new Workbook(memoryStream);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

var printDialog = new PrintDialog();   
var print = printDialog.ShowDialog();
if (print == true)
{
    // Печать workbookBytes или workbook или worksheet
}
```

Comment: Сталкивался я как-то с генерацией документов при помощи aspose, но вот не приходилось их тут же распечатывать. Неплохой вопрос. Подойдёт вариант "установить акробат" (штука, которая почти всегда есть на компе) и [отправить через него](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6103705/5752652)?

Comment: @AK сделал при помощи небольшого велосипеда) Если найду решение получше - то выставлю его) А пока что можете почитать ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал пока что таким образом:

1. Переводим worksheet в Bitmap.
2. Затем Bitmap в BitmapSource
3. После чего открываем окно выбора принтера и отправляем в него BitmapSource

**Код:**

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(workbookBytes);
var workbook = new Workbook(memoryStream);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

var options = new ImageOrPrintOptions
{
    OnePagePerSheet = true,
    ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg
};
var sheetRender = new SheetRender(worksheet, options);
var bitmap = sheetRender.ToImage(0);
var intPtr = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                   BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

var printDialog = new PrintDialog();   
var print = printDialog.ShowDialog();
if (print == true)
{
    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawImage(bitmapSource, new Rect(0, 0, bitmapSource.Width, bitmapSource.Height));
    }
    printDialog.PrintVisual(drawingVisual, "Print Document Image");
}
```